# vue.js router-link does not load component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm new to vue.js and made this `Landing` component, which is linked to `Login` component. What I want to acheive is that when user clicks Login, the login page show up.

```
<template>
        <div>
            <div class="landing">
                <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>

    export default {
        name: 'Landing',
        data: function () {
            return {
            }
        },
        methods:  {

        }
    }
    </script>
```

The main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Materials from "vue-materials"

import Routes from './routes'

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: Routes,
    mode: 'history'
});


Vue.use(Materials)
Vue.use(VueRouter);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    router: router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.Vue :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
        <head>
          <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>

        <NavbarComp/>        
        <Landing/>
        <FooterComp/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavbarComp from './components/Navbar.vue';
import FooterComp from './components/Footer.vue';
import Landing from './components/Landing.vue';
import Login from './components/Login.vue';
import Register from './components/Register.vue';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    NavbarComp,
    Landing,
    FooterComp,
    Login,
    Register
  }
}
</script>
```

routes.js:

```
import Login from './components/Login.vue'; 
import Register from './components/Register.vue'; 
import Landing from './components/Landing.vue'; 

export default [
  {path: '/login', component: Login, name: 'Login'},
  {path: '/register', component: Register, name: 'Register'},
  {path: '/', component: Landing, name: 'landing'},
]
```

And finally, Login.vue:

```
<template>  
  <div>
     <h2>Login</h2>    
   </div>

</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  data: function () {
      return {
        ok: true,
        showErrorRegister: false,
        showErrorLogin: false,
        username: "",
        password: "",
        email: "",
        error: "",            
      }   
  },
```

When I click on Login link, the link in the URL bar changes but the component does not appear, and I don't see any error in the console. So don't know where to go from here.

How can I fix this?

Comment: No, I don't see any error.

Comment: This is a long shot, but if that is exactly what your Login.vue contents are, you are missing a closing curly brace and have an extra comma at the end there. And a missing `</script>`.. If the SFC isn't compiling it might cause it to not show up.

Comment: Well, actually I stripped the components from irrelevant axiom code, so perhaps have missed a curly brace here and there, but I see no error, they should be fine.

Comment: Does your stripped down version work in your environment? I would strip it down as much as you can to see if you can get it working with just the bare minimum.

Comment: Do you have a `<router-view>` anywhere? That's where the Component gets rendered. It should be in App.vue.

Comment: No, I don't have `<router-view>` anywhere. But when I use `<router-view>` instead  of `<router-link>` a window containing the `Landing` module appear in place of the link

Comment: @Karlom can you provide a screenshot of the "Landing" module window appearing. I see you may have confused with the usage of `<router-view>` and `<router-link>`

Comment: @RuChernChong the issue is that I whant to replace `<Landing/>` with `<Login/>` when `<router-link to="/login">Loing</router-link>` is clicked but nothing happens. What I'm confused about?

Comment: Then you are looking at dynamic components here. Use `<component :is=ComponentName>` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: I guess you are right. Can you please elaborate how to use dynamic components in this context? I can not make sense of the docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To elaborate on Cory's comment - which I believe to be the issue.  You are missing `<router-view>`.

Your app currently appears to work because in App.Vue you are rendering the `<Landing/>` component.  You should replace `<Landing/>` with `<router-view/>`.  That way, when the route path is "/", the `<router-view>` will render the `<Landing/>` component in that space - much as it does now.  When the route path is changed (by router-link) to "/Login", the Router will render the `<Login/>` component in that space instead.

Currently the Router is pointing to the correct Login component, however has nowhere to render it.

Read more here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html

Comment: Awsome, thanks for the tip. This resolved the problem.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Comment: This confused me so much, but this answer works. Thank you.